# Can JVM created in Cocoa project make call backs to the Cocoa project?

Tags: cocoa, jvm, java-native-interface

I used JNI to create JVM in my Cocoa project (that has some UI components) and were able to make calls to JVM (another Java app) to start some jobs. Now I want the JVM to be able to call back to tell my Cocoa app the status of a job executed. Is this doable? Is there any samples that I can use as reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current Java UI on the Mac is implemented with Cocoa, of course!  Check out the [Java Native Foundation](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Java-dev/2011/Mar/msg00256.html) framework which provides some simple Java-Cocoa bridge support (note that all the documentation links are currently broken in MobileSafari; use Opera Mini or a desktop browser).  To call from Java to Cocoa you can just use JNI as you would expect.  For sample code you can look at the Mac OpenJDK port - it isn't finished yet but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will take a look of the JNF. Regarding my question, essentially what I am trying to do is Cocoa (app1) -> JNI -> Java (app2) -> JNI -> Cocoa (app1). I have already had the code for the app1 -> app 2 but I want to know whether it's possible to finish up the loop (i.e. app2, after processing, calls back to app1 again, via JNI).